# Nvidia drivers causing malfunction on my USB Ports

Tags: drivers, nvidia, usb

Ubuntu: 22.04 LTS

My laptop have 2 USB Ports, I decided to install nvidia drivers because I read that it could solve some crash issues I had.

But after that I noticed one of my USB ports just don't work properly after installing the drivers, currently, if I apply the `NVIDIA driver metapackage of nvidia-driver-535` only my USB 1 works, but if I apply `NVIDIA driver metapackage of nvidia-driver-470` only my USB 2 works.

Anyone have any ideia how do I make it to default and make my USB ports work again? I tried using the Ubuntu default but it doesn't seem to make any difference, still only one USB works using the `X.Org X Server -- Nouveau display driver of xserverx-xorg-vide-nouveau (open source)`

When I installed the nvidia drivers, it asked me to type and repeat a password for secure boot, I did it.